# Drop section title from selected slides/frames in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, titles, templates, presentations

I am attempting to write/edit my own `beamer` template which currently defines the default frame to show the frame title, and above it, the section title where the slide appears in the presentation, i.e.

```
%% beamerouterthemeMyTheme.sty

...

% Position the frame title so that it would get into the headline
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
\vspace{\dimPlaceTitleInHeader} %% Some predefined dimension elsewhere
\usebeamerfont{section title}\color{black!20}%
    \ifnumcomp{\thesection}{=}{0}{%
        \par%
        }
        {%
        \insertsection\par
        }
\vspace{-1pt}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
%% I do not understand why if I remove this the title does not appear
\ifdefstring{\bWhiteFrame}{true}{\color{white}}{\color{black}}% %% \bWhiteFrame is just some boolean variable that in my context is always false.
\insertframetitle
\vspace{\dimAfterFrameTitleOffset}
}
```

Now, in my presentation preamble, I use the following code, to have the TOC appear right after each `\section` definition:

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen} % package required
\newboolean{sectiontoc}
\setboolean{sectiontoc}{true} % default to true
\AtBeginSection[]{%  %% Do nothing for starred sections
\ifthenelse{\boolean{sectiontoc}}{%
    \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}
}
```

The problem is that in this way, everytime the TOC is shown, it will also show on top the `section title` (which repeats the `currentsection` shown in the TOC) and I would like to avoid it, showing only the TOC with the title `Outline`, but keeping all the other frames in my presentation with the default style (i.e. section title + title).

I have no idea if and how I could achieve this.

Comment: Please provide a _complete example_ (also called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)), it helps others to help you.

Comment: Even after puzzling together your code fragments, it won't compile due to undefined commands. Please add a compilable MWE